# Fresh Vim install, Vim permission errors, Vundle not functional

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, bundle-install, vundle

I have the following vim packages installed on Linux Mint Debian Edition:

```
vim
vim-common
vim-tiny
vim-runtime
vim-doc
```

I had the above packages installed before, and after installing Vundle (it was functional via instructions on http://github.com/gmarik/vundle) decided, to avoid plugin conflicts, to completely remove and reinstall all of the above vim packages/.vim folder, in order to fully utilize Vundle as a means to manage my plugins.  In my file explorer, I can see that the folder created from git cloning `~/.vim` and all inherited folders/files belong to root.  This causes the following problems with Vundle:

First of all when I executed `:BundleSearch` query:

[image: http://imgur.com/ZB2RnR7]

To further diagnose my problem, I tried adding a bundle manually into my vimrc:

```
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
```

Using the exact same vimrc setup in the Vundle GitHub, it worked on the previous installation.
Now when I attempt to `:BundleInstall` I get the following permission-based errors:

```
[140112 13:48:10] 

[140112 13:48:10] Bundle scrooloose/nerdtree

[140112 13:48:10] $ git clone --recursive 'https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git' '/home/ahqiao/.vim/bundle/nerdtree'

[140112 13:48:10] > fatal: could not create work tree dir '/home/ahqiao/.vim/bundle/nerdtree'.: Permission denied\00

[140112 13:48:11] 

[140112 13:48:11] Helptags:

[140112 13:48:11] :helptags /home/ahqiao/.vim/bundle/vundle/doc/

[140112 13:48:11] > Error running :helptags /home/ahqiao/.vim/bundle/vundle/doc/

[140112 13:48:11] Helptags: 1 bundles processed
```

Furthermore, my vimrc also contains the standard two lines for plugins:

```
filetype plugin on

set nocp
```

In the past, I have also had problems with `:helptags` not being able to access `~/.vim/doc` because of permission so I have had to manually copy the help files into a non-root folder and point to that with `:helptags`.

How can I overcome these root problems?  Vundle is really essential for me to manage the amount of plugins I require to code and keep track of.

Comment: How are you cloning `vundle` and where are you putting it? Actually, how did you create `~/.vim` directory? Can you show us the permissions on it?

Comment: git clone https://github.com/gmarik/vundle.git ~/.vim/bundle/vundle

And as stated before the clone worked on previous install.  For some reason VIM is not happy about permissions of my /.vim directory

Comment: If `~/.vim` and all subdirs belong to root, why don't you `chown` to yourself? It seems that is how it should be in `HOME`, but it's unclear to me how it got that way in the first place. Are you saying that when you cloned Vundle this happened?

Comment: after i uninstalled vim the first time, I deleted the entire /.vim directory, when I reinstalled the packages /.vim was not created (I am not sure if VIM does this automatically?) and thus the directory was created as a result of the git clone command (which I ran with normal permission terminal).  Also note that my reinstall processes were done in synaptic with the "complete removal" options checked

Comment: In general, things in your `HOME` directory should belong to your `USER`. You may have run `sudo git clone ...` when installing Vundle before or something else with `sudo` that created the directory but I don't think Vim would ever do that automatically.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's unclear to me how the owner of `~/.vim` got set to `root` but Vundle will definitely have trouble updating packages if that is the case.

If I understand correctly, in that you now have Vim installed how you want it, I suggest redoing the customization process.

---

Move `~/.vim` (for reference) and create the `bundle` directory where Vundle will be installed:

```
$ sudo mv ~/.vim ~/OLDvim
$ mkdir -p ~/.vim/bundle
```

This should now be an empty `dir` owned by your user.

Reinstall Vundle

```
$ git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

Make sure you have the [required lines](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle#quick-start) in your `~/.vimrc`,

- open vim and
- run `:BundleInstall`

Once you got it working and you're happy with everything, you can `rm -rf ~/OLDvim`.

Comment: Recursing through with chown (as in the above comment) appeared to fix my problems.  Thanks bnjmn, would upvote you if I could.  I'm pretty new here, so I really appreiciate your assistance

Comment: This worked for me. Upvoted. Thanks for providing this solution!

Comment: This approach worked for me, but [vundle install instructions](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim#quick-start) are slightly different now.

Answer (score 5):

Changing the ownership of the .vim files to my username instead of root worked for me (did for all files recursively):

```
chown -R <username>:<username> .vim
```

Here's [more info about chown](https://linuxize.com/post/linux-chown-command/).

**Note:** It seems like the reinstall answer would work too (though didn't end up trying it), but with the chown approach you don't have to do the reinstall steps.

Answer (score 1):

It's very late to answer, but this problem still occuring. I run into this problem and Here is how I solved it.
First run the ( get the error while installing the Plugin)

```
    :helptags /home/ahqiao/.vim/bundle/vundle/doc/
```

It will show the Exact Error. In my Case it was Duplicate Entries found in two ale doc file ale-cpp.txt and ale-cpp.txt.

```
    Error: Duplicate Entries Found g:ale_cpp_flawfinder_executable
    Error: Duplicate Entries Found g:ale_c_flawfinder_executable
```

Just **remove these entries or comment out** and Install agin. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Also very late to answer, but in my case, changing the line:

```
call vundle#begin('$USERPROFILE/.vim/bundle')
```

to

```
call vundle#begin('$HOME/.vim/bundle')
```

corrected the problem.  Apparently, $USERPROFILE was not defined, and so evaluated to root (/).

This may help someone....

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling/Installing the offending plugin (`vim-fugitive`) fixed the error for me.

I was getting this error:

```
> Error running :helptags /Users/gigo6000/.vim/bundle/vim-fugitive/doc
```

So I deleted the line:

```
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
```

Run

```
:so %
:PluginClean
:PluginInstall
```

And that did the work.